# Common styles in React-Native

Tags: beginner, css, jsx, react-native

**Background:**
I am completely new to react-native.

**Question:**
Is there any reason why I shouldn’t do this from an experienced point of view?

**Goal:**
- have common styles in my react-native app?
- use advantages of VSCode IntelliSense for development.

```
#common/styles.js

import { Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fontFamily: {
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        fontFamily: 'Baskerville',
      },
      android: {
        fontFamily: 'Noto Sans',
      },
    }),
  },
});

export const fonts = {
  h2: { fontSize: 80 },
  text: { fontSize: 12 },
};

export const BORDER_RADIUS = 5;

export const colors = {
  blue_primary: '#3F51B5',
  blue_secondary: '#E8EAF6',
  green_primary: '#73C700',
  green_secondary: '#F1F8E9',
  white: '#ffffff',
  grey_primary: '#9E9E9E',
  grey_secondary: '#FAFAFA',
  bluegrey: {
    50: '#eceff1',
    800: '#37474f',
    900: '#263238',
  },
};
```

Here is a plain component using this common styles:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { colors, styles, fonts } from './common/styles';

const PlainComponent = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.bluegrey['50'] }}>
    <Text style={[fonts.h2, styles.fontFamily, { color: 'red' }]}>Hello</Text>
  </View>
);

export default PlainComponent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While sharing styles is possible, I find it a little cumbersome and personally, I would **not** do it. Instead, I'd recommend going one level higher: do not share *styles*, share *components*.

That's what React is about - sharing components. In React Native, you won't have to import a component and styles (and pass the styles to the component), you'll just have to import the component. There will be less duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code looks fine and there nothing wrong with creating common style in react native as well. Keeping all this in mind there is one more thing which react native provides is The Higher order Components.

If you want to create common style just to keep it in use like same button style, same text style etc... then I would advice to create respective components and use them instead.